# cannot unzip file after copied it to directory

Tags: c#, xamarin

He guys,

I have a problem with my Xamarin Forms app. There is a embedded resource (Sqlite Database .db3) in my Android project and it is zipped because of its size (unzipped 100MB, zipped 23MB). I tried the whole day to copy it at the launch of the app from the resource Folder to an device internal folder and after that to unzip it at the same folder. All works perfectly as long as it compiles in the debug mode. If I try to compile in release mode or want to use the .apk at my phone the app crashes. 
I have no idea whats wrong with it. I really hope you can help me to solve this problem. 
Maybe you have another solution like unzip the database directly from the resource folder

```
var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
var qbankDbResource = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(name => name.EndsWith(zipName));
using (var qbankDbStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(qbankDbResource))
using (var fStream = new FileStream(zipPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
   qbankDbStream.CopyTo(fStream);
}               
if (File.Exists(zipPath))
                    {
                        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(zipPath))
                        {
                            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipPath), entry.FullName));
                                }
                                catch (IOException)
                                {
                                    continue;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (File.Exists(dbPath))
                        {
                            File.Delete(zipPath);
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: `catch (IOException) { continue;}`  You are silently throwing away any errors, and wonder why it isn't working?  Don't do this!

Comment: Have you checked [the Android Debug Log](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/)? Typically that will show an error when the app crashes.

Comment: What do you mean by _the app crashes_? Try to catch the exception and log it somewhere.

Comment: app crashes mean: it stops and the app disappears.

Comment: First exception (IOException) throws
{System.IO.IOException: Invalid parameter
  at System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime (System.String path, System.DateTime lastWriteTime) [0x00029] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4009/f3074d2c/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:487 
  at System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToFile (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry source, System.String destinationFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x0006b] 
but it goes on and do what it should after the continue statement

Comment: Further I got the Error log from the second exception:
Message: The type initializer for 'SharpCompress.Common.ArchiveEncoding' threw an exception.  

Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal 

Source:

InnerException: System.NotSupportedException: Encoding 850 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct international codeset assembly installed and enabled.
  at System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding (System.Int32 codepage) [0x0025f] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0 
  at SharpCompress.Common.ArchiveEncoding..cctor () [0x0000f] in <00fd1209899640afa6d960ea01ee9813>:0